# use matplotlib.pyplot.plot plot the image with dashed line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am learning the matplotlib. But I can not understand the example in their [official page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_demo_dash_control.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
line, = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '--', linewidth=2)

dashes = [10, 5, 100, 5] # 10 points on, 5 off, 100 on, 5 off
line.set_dashes(dashes)

plt.show()
```

The result is

[image: result]
<sub>(source: [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/_images/line_demo_dash_control.png))</sub>

Question about the code is:

```
line, = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '--', linewidth=2)
```

What means the "," after the line?

Thanks very much for the patient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start for these sorts of questions is always the documentation. [Here's the docs for pyplot.plot()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). Note that about halfway down it says:

> Return value is a list of lines that were added.

So the example uses `line,` instead of  `line` in order to select just the first element in the returned list (which also happens to be the only element in this case). You can check this out for yourself:

```
line, = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '--', linewidth=2)

type(line)
Out[59]: matplotlib.lines.Line2D
```

So `line` is a Line2D object. However, when we omit the comma:

```
line = plt.plot(x, np.sin(x), '--', linewidth=2)
```

We get:

```
type(line)
Out[61]: list

line
Out[62]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f9a04060e10>]
```

So in this case `line` is actually a list that contains one Line2D object.

[Here is the documentation for Line2D.set_dashes()](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_dashes); see if that answers your other question.

Answer (score 1):

The

> ,

generally is to create a tuple.

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037494/python-code-is-it-comma-operator) a detailed explanation.