# TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable when adding second legend to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am making a scatter plot from three separate dataframes and plotting the points as well as the best fit lines.  I can accomplish this using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(111)

#create scatter plots from the dataframes
ax1.scatter(ex_x, ex_y, s=10, c='r', label='Fire Exclusion')
ax2.scatter(one_x,one_y, c='b', marker='s',label='One Fire')
ax3.scatter(two_x, two_y, s=10, c='g', marker='^', label='Two Fires')

#plot lines of best fit
ax1.plot(ex_x,ex_results.predict(), color = 'r',label = 'Linear (Fire Exclusion)')
ax2.plot(one_x,one_results.predict(), color = 'b',label = 'Linear (One Fire)')
ax3.plot(two_x,two_results.predict(), color = 'g',label = 'Linear (Two Fires)')

#add legend and axis labels
plt.xlabel('NDVI 2004/07/27')
plt.ylabel('NDVI 2005/07/14')
plt.title('NDVI in 2004 vs. 2005')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), scatterpoints=1)
```

which gives me:

[image]

Now I want to add a second legend which will display the r2 for each line.  I am attempting to do that like this:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(111)

scat1,=ax1.scatter(ex_x, ex_y, s=10, c='r', label='Fire Exclusion')
scat2,=ax2.scatter(one_x,one_y, c='b', marker='s',label='One Fire')
scat3,=ax3.scatter(two_x, two_y, s=10, c='g', marker='^', label='Two Fires')

lin1,=ax1.plot(ex_x,ex_results.predict(), color = 'r',label = 'Linear (Fire Exclusion)')
lin2,=ax2.plot(one_x,one_results.predict(), color = 'b',label = 'Linear (One Fire)')
lin3,=ax3.plot(two_x,two_results.predict(), color = 'g',label = 'Linear (Two Fires)')

l1 = plt.legend([scat1, scat2,scat3,lin1,lin2,lin3], ["Fire Exclusion", "One Fire", "Two Fires", "Linear (Fire Exclusion)", "Linear (One Fire)", "Linear (Two Fires)"], loc='upper left', scatterpoints=1)

#get r2 from regression results
r2ex=ex_results.rsquared
r2one=one_results.rsquared
r2two=two_results.rsquared

plt.legend([r2ex, r2one, r2two], ['R2 (Fire Exclusion)', 'R2 (One Fire)', 'R2 (Two Fires)'], loc='lower right')

plt.gca().add_artist(l1)
plt.xlabel('NDVI 2004/07/27')
plt.ylabel('NDVI 2005/07/14')
plt.title('NDVI in 2004 vs. 2005')
```

but this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-b6277bf27ded>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/prelim_codes/Fire.py', wdir='E:/prelim_codes')

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "E:/prelim_codes/Fire.py", line 539, in <module>
    scat1,=ax1.scatter(ex_x, ex_y, s=10, c='r', label='Fire Exclusion')

TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same error. I found out that you shouldn't include the comma after your variable names. So try

```
scat1 =ax1.scatter(ex_x, ex_y, s=10, c='r', label='Fire Exclusion')
scat2 =ax2.scatter(one_x,one_y, c='b', marker='s',label='One Fire')
scat3 =ax3.scatter(two_x, two_y, s=10, c='g', marker='^', label='Two Fires')
```

instead of

```
scat1,=ax1.scatter(ex_x, ex_y, s=10, c='r', label='Fire Exclusion')
scat2,=ax2.scatter(one_x,one_y, c='b', marker='s',label='One Fire')
scat3,=ax3.scatter(two_x, two_y, s=10, c='g', marker='^', label='Two Fires')
```

This is because [axes.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) returns a PathCollection unlike axes.plot which returns a tuple of the lines plotted (see http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#controlling-line-properties and [Python code. Is it comma operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037494/python-code-is-it-comma-operator)).

So for your lines you will still need the comma because you are unpacking the tuple but for the scatter you should not have the comma.

Comment: Good god, thank you so much. I've been going insane for 30 minutes until I came across your answer about that **#$%@ comma**!